# How to properply update an entity which contains an Image path?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have a form that I use both for registration and edition of the user informations. This form contains a profile picture property on which I put `@Assert\Image`.

I succeed in creating a new user through my registration form but when I try to edit the user informations (with a `PATCH` method, just to update what need to be updated) I encounter an error with a 'File could not be found' message.

I suppose it's because the path stored in the database is a string and my `@Assert\Image` want an image.

I'm not sure about how I should manage this kind of update.

When I `dd()` the `$user` right after the submission, I see that the `profilePicture` property still contains the path saved in the database.

Here is my function regarding the form handling:

```php
public function myProfile(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user, ['method' => 'PATCH']);

        if ($request->isMethod('PATCH')){

            $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()), false);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                //...
            }

        }
        //if no request just display the page
        return $this->render('connected/myProfile.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'userProfileForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: When you update your user, i guess you don't provide any value to the profile picture field ? If so, you should try to append `'data' => null` to your profile picture field options in your `UserFormType` class. That way, the stored value will not be provided to your form. Also, you should probably define two forms validation groups (for adding/editing a user), in the case you have some constraints (ex. a `@NotBlank`) you want to apply only for the add form. [More details here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Validator will check if your object contains a image and that seems not the case when you’re updating your object.
A workaround is to use `group` [validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html) you define a specific group to the property that have the assert Image and in the method `getGroupSequence` you return the group if you’re in creation (id == null) or if the property is setted.

Comment: It can contains an image during the update, it depends on the user choice to update or not update his profile picture.